# Regex JavaScript - how to check if a string is all letters and then all numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, string, numbers

This would be ok: 'AAAAAAA1222222'
This would be not ok: '1AAAAA'
This would not be ok: 'AA1AA'

Just looking for a way to check if a string is ALL letters and then ONLY letters afterward.

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy one.

```
^[A-Za-z]*[0-9]*$
```

That of course is assuming that no letters is OK.

For example, the above example would match

> ```
> AAAAAAA
> 2222222
> ```

as well as an empty string.

If there must be at least one letter and at least one number, replace the `*` with `+`

```
^[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookahead. Lookaheads are used for validation, I suggest you go through [this](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html).

Try this out: `^(?=[A-Za-z]*\d*$).+`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jF1tG6/2)

Comment: I downvoted it, because at the time you just said "Use a lookahead" (which isn't needed for something this simple), and didn't provide an example.
 Because you've now provided a working example, I've undone my downvote.

Comment: I stil don't understand why you would use a lookahead for this.

Comment: Oh. Well, it's just that I've read that it's a good practice to use a lookahead whenever there is some sort of validation involved: to check if a password contains all the required, validating an email ID etc and only if it's valid, begin the match. So I posted the original reply since this seemed like something that requires validation. Though, I realise this may seem a bit too complicated for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
text.match(/^[A-Z]*\d*$/i)
```

Read this as "start of string followed by any number of letters followed by any number of digits followed by the end of the string."

Note this will match `""`, `"A"`, and `"1"`. If you want there to be at least one letter and at least one number, use `+` instead of `*` in both spots.

Answer (score 0):

try this regex

```
  \b\D+\d+\b
```

\b is the word boundary that won't allow for digits to come in the beginning and letters to come after the digits at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest something like this:

```
text.match(/\b\D+\d+[^\D]\b/);
```

The \b was suggested by Grace and is a good idea. Another option is to use the beginning and end anchors like:

```
text.match(/^\D+\d+[^\D]$/);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+\d*$/);
```

**Tests:**

```
AAAAAAA1222222    -    match
1AAAAA            -    no match
AA1AA             -    no match
AAAAAAA           -    match
2222222           -    no match
```

If you dont want to match **ALL Letters** and **at least one number** change the quantifier of `\d` from `+`(1-infinite times) to `*`(0-infinity times)

more about regex quantifiers : [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374(v=vs.110).aspx)